# how to fix 'Optional.get()' without 'isPresent()'

Tags: java

I have been looking through some threads but cannot find any reference to try to do this to my part of code

```
public static SlotType Motor_IN = new SlotType(
    "motor_in", 
    (t, i, d) ->{
        if(t instanceof TileEntityMachineFrame){
            return Optional.of(
                 (new SlotMotor(
                     ( (TileEntityMachineFrame) t ).itItemHandler.get().motorInputWrapper, 
                     i, d.x, d.y
                  ))
            );
        }
        return null;
     }
);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fix? Also why is this marked `javascript`?

Comment: Don’t return null ever - you have Optional

Comment: Is your question how to fix the warning "'Optional.get()' without 'isPresent()'"?

Comment: `itItemHandler.get()` is that an optional .get? If so you should use is present or alternative get.

Comment: Use `orElseThrow` instead. This should remove the warning.

Comment: If i erased the return null it come up with an error saying i meed a return statment.

Comment: Do i return the orElseThrow in the return that has the null ?

Comment: I just dont know how to fix it perios this is the first time ive used optional

Answer (score 1):

You've left off a bit of information. Right now it appears your code returns `Optional` or `null`. That is the point of Optional though, it might not have anything.

```
if(t instanceof TileEntityMachineFrame){
    //...
} else{
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

That way you return an empty optional and not null. The next issue is your `.get` is giving you a warning. Since it is on an Optional, you have to consider that the Optional will be empty. The simplest replacement would be to replace get with [Optional.orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)). So what happens to your constructor then?

You could replace the `.get` call with map.

```
return ( (TileEntityMachineFrame) t ).itItemHandler.map( 
    handler-> new SlotMotor( handler.motorInputWrapper, i, d.x, d.y )
);
```

From the javadocs for Map, "If a value is present, returns an Optional describing (as if by ofNullable(T)) the result of applying the given mapping function to the value, otherwise returns an empty Optional. "

**Breaking it down more**

I think you've tried to bunch up too much, you should spread it out a bit to better understand what youre doing.

```
Optional<ItemHandler> opt = ( (TileEntityMachineFrame) t ).itItemHandler;
ItemHandler handler = opt.get();
SlotMotor motor = new SlotMotor( handler.motorInputWrapper, i, d.x, d.y);
Optional<SlotMotor> optionalMotor = Optional.of(motor);
```

In that code You're getting a warning because there is a call to get without using `isPresent` one way to change that is to use map.

```
Optional<SlotMotor> optionalMotor = opt.map( 
     handler -> new SlotMotor( handler.motorInputWrapper, i, d.x, d.y )      
);
```

There isn't a missing call to `get` because we're working inside of the lambda passed to map. Plus this automatically gets you the optional you return.

Comment: That gives me an error because not calling handler.get.motorInputWrapper makes it where I cannot get the motorInputWrapper

Comment: @MightyDanp I'm sorry that isn't clear to me. Is `( (TileEntityMachine) t).itItemHandler` an Optional? In your code you call get. I changed it so there is a call to map. You don't need to call get in that case.

Comment: @MightyDanp I've added a more complete description at the bottom.